# When the text field focusing is released by a button selection and the keyboard is dismissed, WKWebView has a blank area as much as the keyboard area

Tags: swift, keyboard, webkit, wkwebview

When the keyboard is released due to text field focusing by pressing another button, a blank area as much as the keyboard area is created.

Is it a problem with webView or webView.scrollView?

[image: Bottom of screen is blue rectangle representing keyboard area. Full screen QebView is underneath the overlaid rectangle.]

Answer (score 0):

Situation

- webView.scrollView has auto created scrollView(WKChildScrollView)
- When keyboard is dismissed by releasing focusing, webView.ScrollView
  has blank area

My Solution

- When keyboard appear, set webView.scrollView's contentInset.bottom to 0
- When keyboard is hiden, set webView.scrollView's contentInset.bottom to -keyboardHeight